# jQuery Ajax: return value to caller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, return-value, return

I have some jQuery code. I have called an Ajax function file, file.php, that has some fields, like:

```
<input type="radio" value="plz">Milk</input>.
```

Will I assign into again jQuery function? If so, how do I do it? I attached a sample file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="examples.css" TITLE="Contemporary" TYPE="text/css">
        <script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-impromptu.1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"file.php",
                    data:id,
                    success:function(){
                        var txt=id;
                        $.prompt( txt,{ opacity: 0.2 });
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        window.location("ERRoR");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `success` function takes a parameter, which contains the fetched data. So in your example:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){ $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"file.php",
       data:id,
       success:function(txt){
          $.prompt( txt,{ opacity: 0.2 });
       },
       // ... more ...
    }
});
```

More examples are in the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#code).

Comment: if I wanted to return HTML data from a php file (such that var data = (success results). Does the above also apply?

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"file.php",
     data:"id1="+val1+"&id2="+val2,
     success:function(data){
       jQuery("#div_id").html(data);
    }
```