# Get json from server into jQuery after posting a form

Tags: jquery, json, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery Ajax Return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388436/jquery-ajax-return-value)

When I fill in a login/register form, the server sends me to a Json page. 
I try to get that json into a js/jquery file, without redirecting to that page.

Can someone tell me how I can get the json data?

To explain what I mean, I show you some code + html pages.

Html form:

```
<form id="registerForm" action="http://localhost:8081/rest/users/register" method="post" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="firstname" class="normalFont"><span rel="localize[register.firstname]">First name</span></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" class="required">
        </td>
        <td class="status">

        </td>
    </tr>

    ... (some other fields)

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Server:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Message register(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String password, String email, String address, String zip, String city, String country) {

    try
    {
        User user = new User();

        user.setFirstname(firstname);
        user.setLastname(lastname);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setAddress(address);
        user.setZip(zip);
        user.setCity(city);
        user.setCountry(country);

        userService.register(user);

        return new Message(true, "Registration Succesful");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new Message(false, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What I get after submitting the form, it's a new HTML page:

```
{"state":true,"content":"Registration Succesful"}
```

How can I get that json into my js file, without going to this html page.

Comment: you might want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388436/jquery-ajax-return-value) using `.ajax()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery to do this. Something like this.

```
$('#registerForm').bind('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        'url': $(this).attr('action'),
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': $(this).serialize(),
        'complete': function(data){
            //data will contain the json coming back
        },
        'error': function(){
            //error occurred
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be right, but after submitting, it always redirect to that json/html page.. why is that?

Comment: I'd have to see the code you have in place to be for sure, the `e.preventDefault()` should be preventing that though.

Comment: (`$('#registerForm').bind('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'http://localhost:8081/rest/users/register',
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': $(this).serialize(),
            'complete': function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            'error': function(){
                alert("errortje");
            }
        });
    });`)

Comment: Sorry for the bad view.. But I can"t find how to add a code block here.. I'm new on stackoverflow ..

Comment: Get rid of the () wrapping everything, and I'm thinking it should work. See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/derekaug/deBRY/ for an example.

Comment: I dont have the (), that was because of the (`code`) block :) But it isn't working.. Is this maybe because my server is in an other project (cross domain vs jQuery...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submiting the form the normal way, you could bind a callback to the submit event. Than serialize the form data with [.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and send it via ajax to your server. For more details see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Something like this:

```
$('#registerForm').on('submit' function(event) {
    $.post("url...", $("#registerForm").serialize(), function(result) {
        // Handle here...
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```